# Java file MD5 and PHP md5_file differ

Tags: java, php, md5

I am having trouble with my md5 hashes in java. To check for file updates I get a listing from my server and compare the files with a local list.

The server file hashes are getting created using the `md5_file()` function in php.
My java code to calculate a file's checksum gives me a different output than excepted.

Some debug output to see the difference:

```
00000.res:b3359dec77910db596b095be7aa49000
00001.res:84411f08999df4fb6ddab1345d21c72c
00002.res:be305453dd435f4a019a1c7b444aff8b
00003.res:66df5d3462287ba6df7bdaa5c32484f2
00004.res:283d977b128e0e7b07de8d4b867f24c9
00000.res:1f012efee3c2c414512a5f19e5f598dd < server
00001.res:fdb212a9280815d98a67be7fe23408d7 < server
00002.res:64151232cc0e6939a024966e8159151c < server
00003.res:f1c9859d2d1f431b76425b11a6a1090e < server
00004.res:0393da6442a0ec153ded0bb6e7e1085c < server
```

The java function:

```
private static final char[] HEX_DIGITS = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'};

public static String getMD5(File file) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException {
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);

    try {
        is = new DigestInputStream(is, md);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[4 * 1024];
        int read;

        while ((read = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            md.update(buffer, 0, read);
        }

    } finally {
        is.close();
    }

    final byte[] data = md.digest();
    final int l = data.length;
    final char[] out = new char[l << 1];

    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < l; i++) {
        out[j++] = HEX_DIGITS[(0xF0 & data[i]) >>> 4];
        out[j++] = HEX_DIGITS[0x0F & data[i]];
    }

    return new String(out);
}
```

I tried searching with google, but all i am getting is md5 hashes for strings. I am pretty sure that my problem has to do something with the md.update() function. Do I copy the buffer the wrong way?

Comment: @jchapa it's not a dup - the OP has a specific bug in this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see you shouldn't be calling `.update` at all - the whole point of the `DigestInputStream` is that it updates the digest *on the fly* as you read it.

You just need to call `.digest` at the end to get the final result.

Comment: Thanks, that solved it. So `DigestInputStream` updates its hash at runtime, good to know!

Comment: I've run into the same problem while trying to correct this answer. Could you post the updated, working code?